# How to run a java jar file on Elastic bean stack

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, elastic-beanstalk

Currently I am using elastic beanstack for drupal application and choose the “Web Server” environment it is pre-defined configuration that uses PHP 5.5 with Apache.

I need to deploy the java API Service on same machine with auto-scaling.

Please find below the commands used for start API service:

1) copy the MKR.jar to the specified location.
2) jar -xvfM MKR.jar
3) nohup java -jar MKR.jar &

Answer (score 1):

You need to write custom SSH commands which ill be executed when the instance in launched.

Elastic beanstalk offers this feature. Read more here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html

Comment: I have created sample file (package.config) under the .elasticbeanstalk Directory. packages:
    yum:
        java: []

container_commands:
    01-command:
        command:        mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/MWB

Comment: It's not working for me ..

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a directory called .ebextensions under the root of your project.

2.Create a file called java.config in that directory and paste the below content.

```
sources:
  /home/ec2-user: http://URL/MXB.jar

commands:
    01_java_start:
        cwd: /home/ec2-user
        command: nohup java -jar mxb.jar > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &
```

**Executed the below command :-**

[root@]# git add .

[root@]# git commit -m "API-Back"

[root@]#git aws.push